# tar creates an empty folder, how do i get rid of it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I have the following line

```
tar -c -v -z -f  "$ARCHIVE_PATH/$3_$fileYear$fileMonth.tar.gz" -C "$ARCHIVE_PATH/tmp" .
```

where

- $ARCHIVE_PATH = /opt/colorado/archive/
- $3 = IMPORT
- $fileYear = 2014
- $fileMonth = 06

so the line creates a `.tar.gz` file called `IMPORT_201406.tar.gz` in `/opt/colorado/archive`/ from the files located in `/opt/colorado/archive/tmp/`

however when i use `tar -ztvf  "opt/colorado/archive/IMPORT_201406.tar.gz"` i see this

```
-rwxr-xr-x root/root        27 2014-06-04 14:20 ./afile.txt
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-06-04 14:08 ./opt/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-06-04 14:08 ./opt/colorado/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-06-04 14:08 ./opt/colorado/archive/
drwxrwxr-x [USER]/[USER]     0 2014-06-04 14:09 ./opt/colorado/archive/tmp/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root       712 2014-06-04 14:20 ./twofile.txt
-rwxr-xr-x root/root       383 2014-06-04 14:20 ./random.cvs
-rwxr-xr-x root/root        27 2014-06-04 14:20 ./helloworld.sh
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      7938 2014-06-04 14:20 ./helloworld.py
```

from my understanding, if i didn't have `-C` the `/opt/colorado/archive/tmp/` would have been added to every file so adding `-C` tells tar to move to that directory first, i can see in the list of files however **why is the `/opt/colorado/archive/tmp/` folder added and is there a way to remove it?**

Comment: There's just one thing that needs to be added. From what directory are you running the tar command?

Comment: @konsolebox from the root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's adding the directory to the archive because you asked it to. Specifically, you told `tar` to archive the directory `.`, so that's what it does. Computers tend to be literal.

If you don't want the directory archived, you'll have to pass the filenames in the directory to tar. Here's one way to do that:

```
(cd "$ARCHIVE_PATH/tmp"; ls) |
tar -cvzf  "$ARCHIVE_PATH/$3_$fileYear$fileMonth.tar.gz" -C "$ARCHIVE_PATH/tmp" -T-
```

Alternatively, you can execute tar from the directory with the files:

```
cd "$ARCHIVE_PATH/tmp"; tar -cvzf  "$ARCHIVE_PATH/$3_$fileYear$fileMonth.tar.gz" *
```

I don't know why you get the directory included with its full path, rather than just `.`, and why it also includes the parent directories in the archive. The version of `tar` on my system (`tar (GNU tar) 1.26`) doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: when i use `tar --version` it says `tar (GNU tar) 1.26`. also i tried changing the `.` to `*` but then  i started getting messages like `tar: var: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`. some of the files it says it can't find are one in the root directory, almost as if using * is trying to archive everything

Comment: @Memor-X: Oops. I should have quoted the `*`; otherwise it gets expanded by the shell instead of tar. I'll fix the answer. Sorry.

Comment: nope, `"*"` outputs `tar: *: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`, also, the archive is empty

Comment: Huh. It's obviously too late here to answer questions. Edited once again, and this time I tested :(

Comment: that's worked now, also like the output better, no `./` after every line which just seemed off for me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

This command will generate the tar file:

tar -cvf new.tar.gz my_dir_to_tar/

where new.tar.gz = tar file name
and my_dir_to_tar/ = directory to make a tar

Comment: that's practically the same as if i didn't have `-C` (except you also omit the -z which is used for the gzip compression) which would then add `/opt/colorado/archive/tmp/` to all the files that are added, i am asking about the empty folder it's created inisde the archive and how i can remove it